# How to auto-slide the homepage carousel with rails views content (not images)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, user-interface

Is it possible to build a landing page, which slide automatically between 3 or 4 different partial views ? Every partial will print a different view of the same data model (not an image slideshow per se), something like top 3 of something, top 3 of something else and so on for infinite loop.

I'm looking for a way to slide on 'pages' instead of  'images', may be loading a full view at the beginning with hidden sections to loop on ?  Or looping on #relative links in the same doc ?

Another thing I thought, was an automatic paginator like [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) or [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) but looping called by an ajax, client side javascript cycle. I don't know if it is praticable and how can be done.

What do you say ? Any suggestion will be welcome
Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As partials are rendered server side you should follow your 'full view' idea. That is, render all of the slides/partials (representations of data as you describe but still slides) then use a javascript slider to display each in turn. This falls back for non-javascript users by displaying all slides.

I want to reiterate that you seem to be confused about server side rendering of partials. You cannot use a ruby daemon or scheduler to do this as you are sending the page to your user; once this has happened you have no control over the page (unless you use javascript to poll your server - I don't recommend you do this).

Comment: yeah, thanks for clarify 'server side' role, and what about a 'client side' javascript cycle which call a paginator ? Any code example ?

Comment: I'd forget about the pagination idea. Have a look at this for a script. http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ which can be used for images, html, text etc. There are lots of scripts of this type, this is for jquery.